# NoSuchElementException on Scanners

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

my code is giving me a NoSuchElementException on every line where the scanner is being used. The rest of my code works fine.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Store
{

 public static void main(String [] args)
{
  Scanner nameScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println (); 
  System.out.println ("Enter your name: "); 
  String name = nameScanner.next();  

  Scanner whatToBuy = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println (); 
  System.out.println ("What would you like to purchase from the store? Please list your items separated by commas: "); 
  String purchase = whatToBuy.nextLine();    


  Scanner howManyToBuy = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println (); 
  System.out.println ("How many would you like to purchase from each item? You must purhase more than one of each item. Please list your items separated by commas. : "); 
  String howMany = howManyToBuy.nextLine();
}

 }
```

Thank You!!

Comment: Change the first `next` to `nextLine`. You've made a typo.

Comment: It's probably because the System.in is not available. Where are you compiling and running this code?. I compiled and ran the code on my machine and it works fine

Comment: @NicholasK tried that already, didn't work

Comment: Can you re-check that again? I've run the same thing, it works. How exactly are you giving the input?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace here

Comment: @Damith Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
 at Store.main(Store.java:14)

Comment: Well are you sure that this is the only code that you execute? I mean this cauases due to unavailability of System.in variable which may close the input stream if you every used scanner.close()

Comment: @nupadhyaya both JGrasp on windows and VSCode on mac

Comment: @Damith these are my only scanners, i never used .close() anywhere

Comment: Well the problem is System.in  input stream is not available for this execution or something like that. I am not really sure what is the root cause to not to initialize the input stream. But surely thats the case here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in your code, could you show trace?
is there any problem with java.util.StringTokenizer?
By the way, you can use only one instance of Scanner. 
e.g.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Store {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
            String name = scanner.next();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(
                    "What would you like to purchase from the store? Please list your items separated by commas: ");
            String purchase = scanner.next();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(
                    "How many would you like to purchase from each item? You must purhase more than one of each item. Please list your items separated by commas. : ");
            String howMany = scanner.next();
            System.out.printf("name:%s purchase:%s howMany:%s",name,purchase,howMany);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many IDEs don't provide a standard input stream. The execution window is a virtual environment where the Java application runs in the background with its output being captured and displayed in the window, but there is no input (no System.in). Try running your application in a Command Prompt window (on Windows) or a Shell terminal window (on Mac).